# 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.' setState() error flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am getting the error quoted above when I try to rebuild a class. The class I am calling, ListOfIngs(), is a class that basically creates a textField, but my goal is to create a large amount of TextFields, the variable countIngs holds the value for the exact number, in a listView. Here is the code:

```
class NewGroceryList extends State<NewGroceryListWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<_ListOfIngsState> _key = GlobalKey();
  final myController = new TextEditingController();
  int countings = 0;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint(myController.text);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Grocery List"),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListsPage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {})
          ],
        ),
        drawer: AppDrawer(),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 30.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Ingredients',
                      style: GoogleFonts.biryani(fontSize: 15.0)),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        countings++;
                      });
                      debugPrint('$countings');
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              setState(() {
                ListOfIngsWidget(countings);
              }),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is the ListOfIngs class/Widget:
class ListOfIngsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final int countIngs;

```
  const ListOfIngsWidget(this.countIngs, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListOfIngsState createState() => _ListOfIngsState();
}

class _ListOfIngsState extends State<ListOfIngsWidget> {
  List<TextEditingController> _controllerList = [];
  List<TextField> _textFieldList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= widget.countIngs; i++) {
      TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
      TextField textField = TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Ingredient $i',
        ),
      );
      _textFieldList.add(textField);
      _controllerList.add(controller);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: Flexible(
        child: ListView(children: _textFieldList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post more code, what type of Variable is countings? I'm assuming int?

Comment: yes, it is an int, I'll see if I can post everything relevant to the question

Comment: Remove the `setState` around the `ListOfIngsWidget(countings);` widget. You cannot put `setState` as part of the children of a Column.
One setState should be enough to rebuild the whole class.

Comment: @AkoraIng.DKB I don't think that worked, the new textField doesn't show up when I press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `setState` around the `ListOfIngsWidget` and add a `UniqueKey()` to it like so:
`ListOfIngsWidget(countings, key: UniqueKey())`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly and is exactly what I wanted. If I wanted to put a gap in between them, would I use a SizedBox, and where would I put it?

Comment: The SizedBox will come right on top of the ListOfIngsWidget in your Column children

Comment: That only worked for the first one, it didn't put a gap between each of them.

Comment: You can play around with the `itemExtent` of the ListView in the ListOfIngsWidget.
Alternatively, you can wrap the `TextField` in a `Padding` and specify either `top`, `bottom`, or `vertical` padding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Interesting, the padding doesn't seem to be changing their gap, no matter how high I set the value.

Comment: child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 150, 50),child: ListView(children: _textFieldList, itemExtent: 50)

Comment: I was saying you put the `Padding` widget around the `TextField` before you add it to the list. With what you did, the padding is around the ListView itself so it does not affect the children.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying, but then I wouldn't be able to name the textField, which would take away my ability to add said textField to the TextFieldList, which then defeats the point of this whole thing:(. Any idea how to go around this?

Comment: You don't need to change the name. You can use `List<Widget> _textFieldList` instead of explicitly declaring the type. This way, you can put any widget at all in it.
Then you can do `_textFieldList.add(Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: textField))`

Comment: ohhhh I see, so you are storing the textField inside of the name, and then adding it inside of a padding.